# How should i indicate an array index inside data-ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

How should i indicate an array index inside data-ng-repeat?. Is it possible to use it in this way?.Here i just indicate my array and what i am try to do with data-ng-repeat.

```
$scope.items=[{'name':'A','address':'AA'},{'name':'B','address':'BB'}];
data-ng-repeat="itm in items[0]"
```

i want to select {'name':'A','address':'AA'} from the array

Comment: Why do you need ng-repeat for this at all? Really not clear what you are asking or what specific problem you are trying to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it...

```
data-ng-repeat="itm in [items[0]]"
```

Don't really see the purpose of the repeat though, could just access `items[0]` directly without repeat.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xakcsftz/1/

```
<div data-ng-repeat="itm in [items[0]]">
  {{itm}}
</div>
```

...

```
$(function() {

  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].setAttribute("ng-controller", "MyController");

  angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
      'name': 'A',
      'address': 'AA'
    }, {
      'name': 'B',
      'address': 'BB'
    }];
  })

  angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
  });

});
```